# How to handle a string that is decoded in an ordered dictionary?

Tags: python, tkinter, ordereddictionary, windows-1252

I have some data converted to an OrderedDict. The problem is that strings that had a "€" symbol in them are now Windows-1252 decoded (at least that's what I think from other questions/answers). When I want to print these strings in a Tkinter label, the "€" symbol won't show.

I've tried to decode the strings when inserting them into a label but it will give me an error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'), which makes sense, looking at the fact that the string stored in the OrderedDict is not a bytestring.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from collections import OrderedDict

dictdata = {'0': OrderedDict([('tab1', '5,20 \x80'), ('tab2', 1), ('tab3', '5,20 \x80')]),
            '1': OrderedDict([('tab1', '5,20 \x80'), ('tab2', 2), ('tab3', '10,40 \x80')]),
            '2': OrderedDict([('tab1', '5,20 \x80'), ('tab2', 5), ('tab3', '26,00 \x80')]),
            '3': OrderedDict([('tab1', '5,20 \x80'), ('tab2', 7), ('tab3', '36,40 \x80')]),
            '4': OrderedDict([('tab1', '5,20 \x80'), ('tab2', 20), ('tab3', '104,00 \x80')])}

text = dictdata["0"]["tab1"]

print(text) # it will print the string with the € symbol

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text=text)   # the € symbol won't show when adding it to a label
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want to have the output of the print() function as my label text.

Comment: Perhaps use [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @IronMan I tried to encode as well as encode and decode the data, nothing seems to work.

Comment: maybe you use font which doesn't have `€`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am using python 3.7

Comment: if I put `€` instead of `\x80` then I see `€` in Label.

Comment: @furas That doesn't seem to be the problem. When switching fonts it still won't work.

Comment: why do you use `\x80` ? Can't you put `€` in text ?

Comment: @furas Yes, if you switch out \x80 for a € symbol in the string itself it works. But I import the data from a csv file (in which there is a € symbol), so that isn't a suitable solution. This OrderedDict is just as an example. All the data I use will look like this.

Comment: then use `replace('\x80', '€')`. For Python it is normal string `'\x80'`, not encoded char. Bytes `b'\x80'` can be decoded `print(b'\x80'.decode('cp1250'))` but not string `'\x80'`

Comment: @furas That's a nice workaround. Thanks for the answer.
I'm still wondering why it won't print this type of string...

Comment: It treats it as unicode with code `\x80` which doesn't have representation in font.  In Label I see short line instead `€`. In terminal I see rectangle with number `0080`. But I think I found encoding `'raw_unicode_escape'` which should resolve problem (if you have other hex codes in string) `print('5,20 \x80'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('cp1250'))`

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be resolved using `encoding='cp1252'` when text is readed from `csv`

Answer (score 1):

It is code of `€` in `Windows-1252` but Python treads it as code in `Unicode` which doesn't have reprezentation in font - so it display weird char or rectangle with code `0080`.

[image] [image]

---

You can replace it

```
print( '5,20 \x80'.replace('\x80', '€') )
```

Or you can try to encode unicode to bytes with `'raw_unicode_escape'` and decode back to unicode with `'cp1252'` (or `'windows-1252'`)

```
print( '5,20 \x80'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('cp1252') )
```

Second method can convert all hex codes in text.

---

Doc: [7.2.4. Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) in [7.2. codecs — Codec registry and base classes](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html)